# Confusion in function overloading in c++

Tags: c++, function, floating-point, overloading

My program has two print functions: one for`int` and one for `float`.

```
void print(float a){
    cout << "float:" << a << endl;
}

void print(int a){
    cout << "integer:" << a << endl;
}
```

Whenever I call `print(10)` or `print(0)` the one for `int` datatype is called. But when I try to call `print(3.5)`, it gives compilation error. Why is it so?

PS when I have only one `print` function `void print(float a)` then `print(3.5)` works fine.

Comment: `3.5` is a `double`. Try `print(3.5f)`.

Comment: Isn't `3.5` also `float`?

Comment: @MairaMuneer no, it's a `double` ;)

Comment: @MairaMuneer Please, when you post a question with compilation error, copy/paste this error in your post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `3.5` is a `double`, not a `float`. And it could be converted to both `float` and `int` implicitly, the invoking becomes ambiguous (`float` with `int`).

See [floating point literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal).

> suffix, if present, is one of `f`, `F`, `l`, or `L`. The suffix determines the
>   type of the floating-point literal:
>
> ```
>     (no suffix) defines double
>     f F defines float
>     l L defines long double
> ```

So you can call it by `print(3.5f);` to avoid ambiguity.

BTW: `double` could be converted to `float` implicitly, that's why if you have only one function then it works well.